# Could not load assembly error when changing to x64 platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, dll, configuration

I have just created a new asp.net 3.5 web application. I went to the application property and changed the platform target to x64. I didn't write any code and i have not changed anything. Next i hit start debugging in Visual Studio. The following error occured:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   "SOLUTION NAME", Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

Any one have an idea how to solve this?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
I have these warnings:

> Warning   1   Assembly generation --
>   Referenced assembly
>   'System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
>   targets a different processor
>   Warning   2   Assembly generation --
>   Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll'
>   targets a different processor
>   Warning   3   Assembly generation --
>   Referenced assembly 'System.Web.dll'
>   targets a different processor
>   Warning   4   Assembly generation --
>   Referenced assembly 'System.Data.dll'
>   targets a different processor

Configuration manager:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem.

It seems that Visual Studio and Cassini run as 32-bit applications. If i try to host my 64-bit ASP.NET application using Microsoft's Cassini, i will get an exception.

So i deployed my solution on IIS, changed it to 64-bit, debugged it and every thing is working perfectly.

Comment: I assume my problem is the same, although it's on IISEXPRESS. I changed the CPY to Any CPU and it works. This should be okay, as the target platform always will go for the best option possible, hence an x64 will run as x64; x86 as x86 and so forth. Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

If you start your app just using F5 or Start button, and you debug on IIS, could be this:

Debug -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects. And select "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects".

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. But i wonder why Microsoft is not intelligent enough to spawn 64 bit version of IIS instead of 32 Bit depending on the proj

Comment: I agree. I lost half a day to figure out, I guess is a deeper explanation I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely to be a 32bit dll that is referenced.

If you are debugging on IIS, open the advanced settings of the application pool and make sure 'Enable 32 Bit Applications' is enabled. That has sorted the issue for a number of times.

Comment: I am debugging in VS (hitting F5). I have updated the question. Any idea about these warnings?

Comment: @Moussa - if you right click on the solution and click Configuration Manager - are all your projects referencing the same CPU type and architecture?

Comment: @WraithNath - I have one project only. It's a new asp.net web application.

Comment: @Moussa - Where have you referenced your System assemlies from? I have not seen it complain about 64bitness of system assemblies before

Comment: @WraithNath - I didn't change anything in the solution. It is a new application. I didn't write any code or added assemblies. I just changed the platform and pressed F5.

Comment: @Moussa - Can you open the proj file in notepad and post its contents?

Comment: @WraithNath - Sorry i misunderstood you when you talked about the Configuration manager. I have adjusted the CPU type and architecture but now i have a different error. 'Could not load type 'WebApplication1.WebForm1'('WebApplication1.aspx inherits from it)

Comment: What did you change the type and architecture to?

Comment: @Moussa - This could be to do with a .net issue. What version are you referencing (right click on your project and select properties.) try running it on .net 2 if you can, and make sure a client profile is not selected

Comment: I tried it with 3 and 2.0 it is the same problem. I you have just created a new web app 3.5 and you want to change the platform to x64 how do you do that? Can you give me the steps so i can try it myself from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

In addition on what @winSharp93 says, have a look at the *Application Pool Advanced Settings* and ensure "**Enable 32 Bit applications**" is set to **false**.

Comment: I am debugging in VS (hitting F5). I have updated the question. Any idea about these warnings?

Comment: Where is this setting? Application Pool Advanced Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all dlls you compile are for 'any cpu' or are compiled for 'x64'. You can find this on the project settings window for each project.

Comment: I just have one asp.net application.

Comment: Yes - so look at the project compilation settings for it and ensure it says 'any cpu' :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your references in the solution.Probably that is pointing to the old dlls.