# unable to find references

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am referencing one dll in my Project called `Something.dll`

When i try to Call Methods from that dll i get error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Something, Version=1.2.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=57732cb8f5e77948' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

My web.config reads like

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Something" publicKeyToken="57732cb8f5e77948" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.0.1" newVersion="1.2.0.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

How do i get read of this issue. I dont have any dll With that name having Version 1.2.1.1. I am using Visual studio 2013.

Comment: How did you reference `Something.dll`? Did you install a Nuget package, or did you add the reference by hand?

Comment: @Dido i tried both ways

Comment: Try setting the `publicKeyToken` to `null`.

Comment: @Dido even though i added null it still Returns me same publickeytoken

Comment: It might be the target platform of the dll and your program are incompatible, [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437606/could-not-load-assembly-error-when-changing-to-x64-platform)

Comment: @Dido so what to do now?

Comment: if you installed it as a nuget package, you should be able to see which .NET framework it targets. Is it the same as the target framework of your project?

Comment: @Dido its Our custom dll which we developed so i dont see target framework

Comment: @MikeMat its not same question as mine and error Message is different too

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you can remove the dependent assembly section in the config file to prevent any unintended binding redirects. It would help to open and check the contents of .csproj file (the project file) of the project that references that DLL. If the reference points to a specific version of the DLL with a public key, you can remove the version and public key part and try building again. If this doesn't work, you can try deleting and re-adding the reference in the project.